# Reduce maximum value in multiple columns by one in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

Bit of a niche one here that I've not been able to find equivalent code for anywhere. I simply want to find the maximum value in some of the columns (not all of them) and reduce this maximum value by one. It will be a single row, not multiple rows that have the maximum value.

So let's say I have a table with the following columns. I want to reduce the maximum value in columns A, B and D by one:

```
A B C D
3 2 5 5
4 9 6 7 
7 0 7 9 
1 3 9 1
```

...to produce a table with the maximum reduced by one in columns A, B and D.

```
A B C D
3 2 5 5
4 8 6 7 
6 0 7 8 
1 3 9 1
```

(I'm actually working with a table of about 40 rows, about 8 of which I want to reduce the maximum value by 1 within). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create mask by compare maximal value and subtract `1` for matched values, it working because `True` is processing like `1`:

```
cols = ['A','B','D']

df[cols] -= df[cols].eq(df[cols].max())

print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  3  2  5  5
1  4  8  6  7
2  6  0  7  8
3  1  3  9  1
```

For general solution is possible multiple mask by `N`:

```
cols = ['A','B','D']

N = 2
df[cols] -= df[cols].eq(df[cols].max()).mul(N)

print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  3  2  5  5
1  4  7  6  7
2  5  0  7  7
3  1  3  9  1
```

Comment: What's confusing me is that all my columns are floats and when I do the above I get the error:

Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with DatetimeArray is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`"  .... even though the arrays I'm editing are not DateTime arrays...

Comment: @RichardDixon - also second solution?

Comment: Yes, with the 2nd solution, too.

Comment: @RichardDixon - Is possible there is some datetimes column(s) ?

Comment: @RichardDixon - Tested and got it, answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) with the [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html)-1 and [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'D']

df.update(df[cols].clip(upper=df[cols].max()-1, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  3  2  5  5
1  4  8  6  7
2  6  0  7  8
3  1  3  9  1
```